# Would like to use wildcard within an xpath

Tags: xpath

I have two links on a page that have the text 'London'.  I want to choose the second one on the page, but I want to define the xpath in a way that it chooses by the parent div, but I want to use wildcard in case the link is moved.

So, the two xpaths are

```
//div[@id="first-id"]/div/div[2]/a[text()="London"]

//div[@id="second-id"]/div[2]/div[3]/div/a[text()="London"]
```

I want to use a wildcard and define the xpath within the parent div:

i.e. `//div[@id="second-id"]/*/a[text="London"]`

I already understand I can just use the full xpath and not have any wildcards, but I want to know if there's a way to do what I am proposing using xpath.  I thought maybe contains() in some way would work but am not familiar enough with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the `a` element wherever it may appear within the `div` element, the descendant path is represented simply by `//`:

```
//div[@id="second-id"]//a[text="London"]
```